# Storing the $date variable into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in storing the $date variable in the database column called data of type  `varchar(50)`

This is the code of the date variable

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
echo $date;
```

and this is the code that stores it into the database (notice that the date is the same one)

what is the problem with my code

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO 
    Students(FirstName, LastName,gender,Major,Favorite_courses,GPA,date)
 VALUES 
    ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[sex]','$_POST[major]',
     '$_POST[favorite]','$_POST[GPA]','$date')";
```

Comment: Any reason the column type isn't of type `DATE`?  Also, are you getting error messages?  What IS happening?

Comment: 1st, What's the problem,  2nd, why are you spring it in a carchar field?

Comment: OH! You must be the people who are good friends with [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: O, hai, [Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)! Ever heard of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)? I'd worry about that first...

Comment: FYI, you are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use preapred/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: no problem I can make it with date datatype then what shall I do my friends

Comment: I am not getting any error message I just wanna post the date into the database but nothing happening can you give me any method??

Comment: This is just my 3rd project in web programming course I do not care if any one hack it I think that will be my honor to get my project hacked ,, but thank you to tell my about PDO this is the first time I hear about it :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the column type to `DATE` and then use `SYSDATE` as the value to input the current date/time on the SQL server.

Also, read up on SQL injection!

Comment: Do note that `SYSDATE()` uses the time of the server running the RDBMS which *does not* have to be the same host as the one running the PHP script so there's a possibility these dates do not match if they are just "out of sync" or set to, or actually in, different timezones etc.

Comment: Good point, @RobIII. Is there a way to format to a specific timezone when using `SYSDATE`?

Comment: I did that but still nothing happening, this is my code what is the mistake on it
______________
$sql="INSERT INTO Students(FirstName, LastName,gender,Major,Favorite_courses,GPA,date)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[sex]','$_POST[major]','$_POST[favorite]','$_POST[GPA]','SYSDATE')";

notice I put SYSDATE in the end

Comment: SYSDATE is not a string so you need to remove the quotes around it; also you need to escape `date` because it's a reserverd word unless I'm mistaken): `$sql="INSERT INTO Students(FirstName...,\`date\`) VALUES (...,SYSDATE())";`

Comment: @nhinkle: As [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904818/storing-the-date-variable-into-mysql-database-using-php/16904927?noredirect=1#comment24397419_16904927) suggests: I wouldn't use SYSDATE in the first place (unless I specifically wanted the RDBMs' time). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16905250/215042) on how I would go about it.

Comment: Thank you sir ,, every thing you said is just right now it is working fine but I still a beginner who can I correct my code to make everything secured from attacks of fatal errors ??

Comment: @AhmedAl-sabsab: There are more than enough links in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16905250/215042) to help you get started. You can't expect us to write a complete tutorial on this matter here on Stack Overflow when all the information you need is already available in the *documentation*.

Answer (score 2):

Technically your code should work, but in practice it will undoubtedly fail.

For starters you should never put POST data directly into your database. Depending on what's in that data, it will at the least break your SQL statement. It could also destroy your database if someone entered some SQL into a POST variable.

Don't do it that way. You need to sanitize any data coming from the outside world before inserting it into the database. There are several PHP database classes that do this for you. I like [PDO](http://php.net/PDO).

Also, write better PHP by using $_POST['favorite'] instead of $_POST[favorite]. What happens if you do this in your code somewhere `define('favorite', 'foobar')`?

What happens is that your code will than look for $_POST['foobar'] instead of $_POST['favorite'].

You really need to work on your knowledge of PHP and SQL before rolling anything out into the wild, or you're going to have problems. But keep plugging along, you'll get it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the, already several times mentioned, [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection): use [`date('c')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (or more specifically: [ISO8601 notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). That will result in code like:

```
$query = "insert into mytable (myfield) values ('" . date('c') . "')";
```

Which will result in a query like:

```
insert into mytable (myfield) values ('2013-06-03T22:20:32+02:00')
```

This is an unambigious notation and should always work (`Y-m-d` will work fine too, as per your question, it only stores a date without any time). When using any other notation there's always the problem for the RDBMS that it has to know wether it has to interpret `02/12/1977` as February 12th 1977 or December 2nd 1977. Also, make sure that `myfield` (in my example) is of type `DateTime` or `Date` and **not** `varchar` and that you correctly escape [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `date` in querystrings:

```
select foo, bar, `date`, foobar from mytable....
```

However, MySQL seems to 'allow' `date` (because of "[MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)." wich is a stupid reason). It's best to just stick to escaping *always*:

```
select `foo`, `bar`, `date`, `foobar` from `mytable` ....
```

Please note that I did **not** use any sort of [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in this example; you should go read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and then on those topics and *then* go back to your code.

Comment: wow that's a lot master @Roblll I will do my best to develop my self thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can use the php class Date and use his format function