# Putting multiple checkbox answers in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a checkbox asking the user to put his/her favorite courses.  I want to store all the selected courses in one column separated by delimiters in MySQL database

This is the way I insert it into mysql database. How should I be doing this?

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Students(FirstName, LastName,gender,Major,Favorite_courses,GPA,Date_of_reg)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[sex]','$_POST[major]','$_POST[favorite]','$_POST[GPA]',SYSDATE())";
```

$_POST[favorite] is the field in question.

Comment: You should read up on sql injection and database normalization. This is definitely not the way to do it.

Comment: Oh, hello there [Bobby](http://xkcd.com/327/). I'd like you to meet my good friend [Prevention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: We [just told you yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904818/storing-the-date-variable-into-mysql-database-using-php) that you need to deal with your sql injection problems before proceeding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Students(FirstName, LastName,gender,Major,Favorite_courses,GPA,Date_of_reg) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[sex]','$_POST[major]','implode(\',\',$_POST[\'favorite\'])','$_POST[GPA]',SYSDATE())";
```

Comment: Not a well-formed answer. Some details should be added. A single line of code doesn't explain so much.

Comment: Literally this comment took more effort than the answer. There is so much more wrong with the question than we have time or space for here so I'm just providing the fix as-is. No details should be added.

Comment: Considering the form of the question I think your answer in this form would be rather confusing than helpful.

Comment: can you please right the whole code because this is not clear enough for me

Comment: No, Ahmed, SO is not a can-i-get-a-slave-so-I-can-sit-drinking-my-wine site... Slavery ended a few centuries ago in the western world and I, for one (and I'm sure the others would agree), see no sense in reviving it in 2013.

Comment: Sorry but the code is not working there is syntax error message ..
thank you for the lyrics hd1

Answer (score 2):

If you REALLY want to put all favorite courses into a single field, you can make this field a string, and store the PHP array in it by serializing it. You can use the `serialize()` function, or JSON, `json_encode()`, or any other similar method. To retrieve the data, just use `unserialize()`, or `json_decode()`, and you will have your array back in PHP.

But keep in mind that using a SELECT statement to filter who likes course foo or course bar, will be quite dificult. The best approach is to follow jeroen's suggestion, normalizing your data.

Comment: please I want a direct answer the serialize function looks complicated for me

Comment: It's not. These functions can turn an array into a string and back to an array. In 5 minutes you can learn how it works, and it's your only hope to do it in a more or less clean way.

Comment: I will do my best 
what about this quastion can you answer it please [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927341/creating-and-coding-save-and-submit-buttons-in-php)

Comment: If it's just an array of integers, a comma separated list is a much better option.  mysql has functions which allow queries against comma separated lists; serialized data is useless until you parse it in php.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for security and normalization reasons you shouldn't do that.

However, you can do it, if you really want to by using the function serialize() of php.

```
$myFavorites = serialize($_POST[favorite]);
$sql="INSERT INTO Students  (FirstName, LastName, gender, Major, Favorite_courses, GPA, Date_of_reg) VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]' ,'$_POST[lastname]' ,'$_POST[sex]' ,'$_POST[major]', '$myFavorites', '$_POST[GPA]', SYSDATE())";
```

You'll be able to unserialize it after you got it from your database with

```
$serializedCourses = myFunctionToGetItFromMyDatabase();
$unserializedCourses = unserialize($serializedCourses);
```

What I would do would be to create another table in your database for the Courses, and link it to the user via the user's id.
For example you could create as much columns as there is type of courses, and that will make you able to get easily the list of people who like Maths (for example) or even Maths and Geometry.

You won't be able to do that with your solution easily.